# Match everything until parenthesis with digits inside

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to get the text before the text like `(2)` in a pattern similar to `[(\d)]`

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^[^(\d*)]+')
text = 'Graduate (Degree-seeking) (2)'

pattern.findall(text)
```

I only got `['Graduate ']` from the code I compiled up there.

**The desired output should be** `['Graduate (Degree-seeking)']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture in a group as least as possible chars until the first occurrence of only digits between parenthesis.

```
^(.+?)\s*\(\d+\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SqS9WH/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5rcAOH)

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^(.+?)\s*\(\d+\)')
text = 'Graduate (Degree-seeking) (2)'
print(pattern.findall(text))
```

Output

```
['Graduate (Degree-seeking)']
```